# После обновления Xcode до 10.2 в WebView приложения начала крашится выводя ошибку Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift, xcode, webview

у меня другой проект думал дело в проекте но потом просто создал WebView проект и там тоже такая ошибка. (основной проект все работает нормально но именно при переходе к контроллеру с WebView он крашится) плс помогите буду очень признателен!

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webbView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url1 = URL(string: "https://www.mail.ru/")


    webbView.load(URLRequest(url: url1!))

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

На экране настроек проекта, в разделе Target в самом низу Linked Framework and Libraries, надо нажать плюсик и добавить WebKit.framework.

Comment: Попробовал, все равно крашится, на optional тоже поставил тоже крашится

Comment: Перед тем как ответить, я конечно же создал тестовый проект и проверил, что ничего не крашится после добавления WebKit.framework